# I can't access Wordpress Dashboard./js/code/a_0.txt was not found on this server NOT FOUND ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting this error message:

Not Found

The requested URL

> **Not Found**
>   /js/code/a_0.txt

The bigger problem is, I can't access dashboard. There's no login box, instead all I can see is blank white page with 2 of those "NOT FOUND" error messages on top. So I can't login and access dashboard

was not found on this server.

[image: Error]